# Is a bitstring easier to compress if it has lower Kolmogorov complexity?

Tags: data-compression, kolmogorov-complexity

I have two bitstrings that are 100 bits long.  Bitstring A has a Kolmogorov complexity (KC) of 90 and bitstring B has a KC of 10.  Intuitively, I think bitstring B is probably easier to compress than bitstring A.

"Easier to compress" means a larger proportion of 100 bit bitstrings with B's KC can be compressed by a standard compression algorithm, than bitstrings with A's KC.

What I mean is that B probably has much more regularity that can be exploited by a compression algorithm such as Lempel-Ziv, whereas A is probably much more random and irregular.

Is this intuition correct?  If so, how is this relation quantified?  Can I say B is 9 times as likely to be compressible than A?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "easier"?  I don't think the question is well-defined.  In particular, I don't think there's any formal, well-defined notion of "easier to compress".   You can certainly say that B's compression ratio is 9 times as high as A's compression ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your intuition is not correct. We can't effectively reason over the space of all programs, even all programs up to a given size (e.g. 90 for A and 10 for b) and it's not certain what the units are in your given KC measures for B and A.

As a simple example, imagine a program B that decompressed a highly compressible message and then encrypted it using some cipher and a hardcoded key. And imagine a different program A that simply output a hardcoded random string of the same length as the one produced in B. Given a long enough output, you could make K(output(B)) << K(output(A)), but both would be highly uncompressible without having the decryption key for B available.

What you're talking about sounds something like this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_probability. It is uncomputable, but if you are willing to e.g. limit the execution time of programs and randomly sample from random programs, you can start to analyze very simple examples.

Comment: This is a good exceptional case, but is it a typical case?  While particular bitstrings with low KC may be very difficult to find a decompressor, is this the case with most bitstrings of low KC?